# Why set css by using selector $(':dragged') makes the dragging movement awkward?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-draggable

I use the following code to make the element being dragged turn to be transparent when it is over a connected sortable list.

```
$(':dragged').css({'opacity': 0.5});
```

The issue is that, after using this, the dragging movement is not as fluent as before and the cursor sometimes has an offset from the element being dragged.

Why it is like this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Just a theory, but maybe the ":dragged" event is triggered on every mouse movement which would make things slower. An alternative would probably be to set the opacity when the element is initially dragged and then turn it off when it's dropped.

Comment: Did you try using opacity option of draggable? https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-opacity

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the way you're doing it will cause the CSS to be updated constantly while the object is being dragged.

This is clearly something that is going to cause even the best browser to stutter.

What you may want to do instead is bind the opacity change to the `drag` event, and then set it back again when the dragging is stopped:

```
$('.draggableClass').bind('drag',function( event ){
    $(this).css({'opacity': 0.5});
});
$('.draggableClass').bind('dragstop', function(event) {
    $(this).css({'opacity': 1.0});
});
```

This way the CSS change will only occur once when the dragging starts and once more when it finishes, rather than hundreds of times every minute during the dragging as is happening with your code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! But bind 'drag' with '.draggableClass' turns the whole list of draggable elements into opacity. The effect I want is only the one element being dragged to be transparent. That's why I was considering to use ':dragged'. BTW, these two methods actually makes each element can be dragged only once.